# Distribution of "occupation times" of Brownian Motion

Tags: stochastic-processes, integration, stochastic-calculus, brownian-motion

Let $B_t(\omega)$ be a standard Brownian motion and let $A\in\mathcal{B}(\mathbb R)$ be a Borel set.
I would like to find the distribution of $$Y_A(\omega):=\lambda(\{t\in[0,1]:B_t(\omega)\in A\})=\int_0^1\mathbf1_{B_t(\omega)\in A}dt.$$
In particular, I would be interested in sets of the form $A=[-a,a]$ for $a>0$.

I was able to compute the first moment in a closed way.
\begin{align*}
    \mathbb E[Y_A]&=\int\int_0^1\mathbf1_{B_t\in A}dtd\omega=\int_0^1\int\mathbf 1_{B_t\in A}d\omega dt\\
&=\int_0^1\mathbb P[\mathcal N(0,t)\in A]dt=\int_0^1\int_A\frac1{\sqrt{2\pi t}}\exp\left(-\frac1{2t}x^2\right)dxdt\\
&=\int_Ax\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac x{\sqrt{2}}\right)-|x|+\sqrt{ \frac2\pi}\exp\left(-\frac{x^2}2\right) dx\\
&\overset{A=[-a,a]}=\mathrm{erf}\left(\frac a{\sqrt{2}}\right)-a^2\mathrm{erfc}\left(\frac a{\sqrt{2}}\right)+\frac{2a}{\sqrt{ 2\pi}}\exp\left(-\frac{a^2}2\right)
\end{align*}

For higher moments I think it is possible to do something similar
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Y_A^n]&=\int_{\Omega}\left(\int_A\mathbf 1_{B_t(\omega)\in A}\mathrm d t\right)^n\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\int_{\Omega}\int_{A^n}\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbf 1_{B_{t_j}(\omega)\in A}\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\mathrm d\omega\\
&=\int_{A^n}\int_{\Omega}\prod_{j=1}^n\mathbf 1_{B_{t_j}(\omega)\in A}\mathrm d\omega\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\\
&=\int_{A^n}\mathbb P\left[\bigwedge_{j=1}^nB_{t_j}\in A\right]\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\\
&=n!\int_{A^n_{\mathrm{ord}}}\mathbb P\left[B_{t_1}\in A\wedge\bigwedge_{j=2}^n B_{t_j}-B_{t_{j-1}}\in A-B_{t_{j-1}}\right]\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\\
&=n!\int_{A^n_{\mathrm{ord}}}\mathbb P\left[Z_1\in A\wedge \bigwedge_{j=2}^n Z_j\in A-\sum_{i=1}^{j-1}Z_i\right]\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\\
&=n!\int_{A^n_{\mathrm{ord}}}\int_{z_1=-a}^a\phi_{t_1}(z_1)\int_{z_2=-a-z_1}^{a-z_1}\phi_{t_2-t_1}(z_2)...\int_{z_n=-a-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i}^{a-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i}\phi_{t_n-t_{n-1}}(z_n)\mathrm d z_n...\mathrm d z_2\mathrm d z_1\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\\
&=n!\int_{z_1=-a}^a\int_{z_2=-a-z_1}^{a-z_1}...\int_{z_n=-a-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i}^{a-\sum_{i=1}^{n-1}z_i}
\left(\int_{A^n_{\mathrm{ord}}}\phi_{t_1}(z_1)\prod_{j=1}^{n}\phi_{t_j-t_{j-1}}(z_n)\mathrm d t_1...\mathrm d t_n\right)\mathrm d z_n...\mathrm d z_2\mathrm d z_1
\end{align*}
Where $Z_j\sim\mathcal N(0,t_j-t_{j-1})$, $\phi_t(x)$ is the density of $\mathcal N(0,t)$ and $A^n_{\mathrm{ord}}=\{(t_1,...,t_n)\in A^n:t_1\leq t_2\leq...\leq t_n\}$.

For instance, the second moment would be
\begin{align*}
\mathbb E[Y_A^2]&=\frac1\pi\int_0^1\frac1{\sqrt{t_1}}\int_{t_1}^1\frac1{\sqrt{t_2-t_1}}\int_{-a}^a\exp\left(-\frac{x_1^2}{2t_1}\right)\int_{-a-x_1}^{a-x_1}\exp\left(-\frac{x_2^2}{2(t_2-t_1)}\right) \mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_1\mathrm dt_2\mathrm dt_1\\
&=\frac1\pi\int_{-a}^a\int_{-a-x_1}^{a-x_1}\int_0^1\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x_1^2}{2t_1}\right)}{\sqrt{t_1}}\int_{t_1}^1\frac{\exp\left(-\frac{x_2^2}{2(t_2-t_1)}\right)}{\sqrt{t_2-t_1}} \mathrm dt_2\mathrm dt_1\mathrm dx_2\mathrm dx_1
\end{align*}
And now I don't know how to proceed. Do you have any idea how (assuming it is possible) to compute these integrals in a closed form? Are there other techniques that can be used to understand the distribution of $Y_A$?

Comment: Distribution of local times at a fixed times are not simple. An approach is to work at an exponential independent time with parameter $\lambda$ (at this time, Ray's theorem or first Ray-Knight theorem applies), and then to invert a Laplace transform to deduce the distribution at a given fixed time. Yet, this strategy may be difficult to follow.

Comment: a better keyword is "occupation times". As mentioned in the previous comment the main approach is with Laplace transform eg. "A sharp upper bound for the expected interval occupation time of Brownian martingales" and "Distributions of occupation times of Brownian motion with drift".